# Как потоки синхронизируются между собой

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как я понимаю, каждый поток работает в данными которые находятся в кэше на котором выполняется поток. допустим три поток выполняются в трех ядрах одновременно с одними и теми же данными. Первый поток делал какие то изменения и завершился. В этом случае как я понимаю происходит синхронизация данных первого потока со всеми кэшами процессора. (если конечно я правильно понимаю) 1. Но что если будет конфликт с данными из других кэшов(как будут мерджиться)? 2. Меня интересует как происходит синхронизация, данные сбрасываются в ram и говорит другим ядрам типа скачай данные с ram там более актуальные данные?

Comment: про синхронизацию и состояние гонки слышали?

Comment: советую прочитать книгу от разработчиков языка, в которой описывается Java Memory Model и принципы работы многопоточного кода в JVM с ссылками на более продвинутые источники (Java Concurrency in Practice: Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ох, это очень сложный вопрос, ответы на который лежат в [Java Memory Model](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133) и Hardware Memory Model. Последняя может ещё и отличаться для разного оборудования.

Прежде всего, завершение потока не гарантирует синхронизации его данных. Данные либо должны иметь модификатор `volatile`, либо доступ к ним должен осуществляться в пределах синхронизированных блоков.

Если совсем кратко описать синхронизированный доступ к данным, то в момент входа потока в синхронизированный блок и выхода из него, процессоры потратят кучу времени на синхронизацию кэшей и памяти. Именно поэтому синхронизацию нельзя использовать бездумно.

Если быть чуточку подробнее и рассмотреть *железные* детали этого процесса, у процессоров есть протокол когерентности кэшей, позволяющий синхронизировать изменения данных в кэшах и не дёргать лишний раз контроллер оперативной памяти. Синхронизация происходит по общей для кэшей всех ядер и контроллера памяти шине. В упрощённом виде (отбросив два из пяти состояний кэшированных данных, а также игнорируя store buffers и invalidation queue) это выглядит так:

1. Процессор №1 делает запрос на блок данных №42.
2. Локальный кэш процессора №1 обнаруживает, что таких данных в нем нет (либо нет вообще, либо они есть в состоянии Invalid).
3. Кэш процессора №1 открывает на шине транзакцию "дайте мне блок данных №42".
4. На запрос отвечает контроллер оперативной памяти пересылая нужный блок.
5. Данные записываются в кэш процессора №1 в состоянии Shared.
6. Процессор №1 изменяет блок данных №42, кэш этого процессора отсылает по шине "я изменил блок данных №42" и устанавливает блоку состояние Modified.
7. Процессор №2 имел в кэше этот блок, он помечает его как Invalid.
8. Процессору №2 понадобился блок №42.
9. Кэш процессора №2 отправляет по шине "дайте мне блок данных №42".
10. Процессор №1 обнаруживает, что у него в кэше этот блок в состоянии Modified, и отправляет по шине "прервать транзакцию" и "запись блока №42 в память".
11. Кэш процессора №2 ждёт завершения транзакции процессора №1.
12. Кэш процессор №2 возобновляет предыдущую транзакцию.
13. Контроллер памяти отдаёт процессору №2 актуальный блок №42 из оперативной памяти.
14. Процессоры №1 и №2 помечают блок №42 в своих кэшах как Shared.

Пара статей на Хабре на эту тему - [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143237/) и [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209128/). А также весьма познавательными могут быть запросы в Google "java memory model", "memory barriers", "memory ordering" и "happens before". Ну, и нельзя в таких вопросах не дать [ссылку на Шипилёва](https://shipilev.net/).

Comment: 1. Как я понял вы описали принцип работы с volataile? 2. А что если два потока одновременно изменили данные?

Comment: JMM этого не позволяет. Как только один поток начнёт изменять volatile-переменную или войдёт в синхронизированный блок, второму потоку придётся ждать.

Comment: можно ли в таком случае сказать что volatail это микро synchronized?

Comment: Да, volatile - это слабая форма синхронизации.

Comment: Спасибо, разъяснили.

Comment: и еще как часто сбрасываются данные из локального кэша в ram обычной переменной?

Comment: На аппаратном уровне только по мере надобности - либо в процессе вытеснения из кэша новыми данными, либо на пункте №10. На программном, при переходе через любой memory barrier, который может быть установлен на обращении к волатильной переменной, блоке синхронизации или входе в [safepoint](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.ru/2015/12/safepoints.html).